# R rlm model error: 'x' is singular: singular fits are not implemented in 'rlm'

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have this two lists in R:

```
y=c(420.5568, 693.6305, 420.5568, 946.9677, 499.1046, 946.9677)
x=c(32, 29, 32, 27, 31, 27)
```

I'm trying to fit this data to `rlm` model using this code:

```
fit_new = (rlm(log(tail(y, 3)) ~ poly( tail(x,3), 2, raw=TRUE )))
```

The response is this error:

```
 Error in rlm.default(x, y, weights, method = method, wt.method = wt.method,  : 
'x' is singular: singular fits are not implemented in 'rlm'
```

Comment: You have duplicated elements within your data. Remove them and you'll be fine.

Comment: @tonytonov Thank you! Add it as an answer please to give you a feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrapping up my earlier comment: there's a problem is with the input data. Namely, there are duplicate pairs `(x, y)`. Regression algorithms usually work on matrices, and if a matrix has identical rows or columns, its' determinant is zero. Some algorithms can take care of that; some don't.

Here's a minimal ad-hoc fix for your data: use `unique` to remove duplicates. Be careful though: as a general solution, you'll have to remove duplicate *pairs*, not only duplicates within `x` and `y` separately.

Comment: I get this error from `MASS::rlm()` but I don't have any duplicated rows. So there is at least one other way to get this error. In my case, only arises when a certain factor variable is used, and does not happen with `lm()`.

Comment: Just to add to @CoderGuy123 comment above. If you have a factor where some levels don't have instances, this can also cause this error. See https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Avoiding-singular-fits-in-rlm-td947387.html.